# Line break turns to a rectangle symbol when sheet saved as PDF

Tags: excel, save-as, vba

If I add a `vbNewLine`, `vbCr` or `vbLf` in a cell, and when I convert sheet to a PDF file, either using `WorkSheet.SaveAs PdfFile, 17`, `Worksheet.ExportAsFixedFormat`, or manually use <kbd>Save As</kbd> or <kbd>Export</kbd> they turn into a little rectangle symbol.

[image]

How do I avoid this?

Comment: Maybe try to Replace those three characters with a " " before to convert. The little square means that the char is not rendered in PDF (so it remains empty)

Comment: I have not only 3 characters, i have a lot of them and they changes dinamicly acording on that user selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this hapens when you trying to add newline as `vbCrLf` ? Then try use only `vbLf`

Answer (score 0):

I know it an old trend but for me it worked using `vbLf` as newline command.